Access Logic App Parameters in PowerShell script code in Standard workflows
I started learning how to do "PowerShell script code in Standard workflows". seams good solution.
I tried to access the logic app parameters with:
$Cert = (@{parameters('CertificatePFX')} )
$domain =( @{parameters('AADDomain-(Prod)')}  )

But I get error:
PowershellFunctionFailed
The inline code action 'Powershell' execution failed, with error 'At C:\home\site\wwwroot\wf-ReduceProposals\execute_powershell_code.ps1:8 char:22 + $Cert = (@{parameters('CertificatePFX')} ) + ~ Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal. At C:\home\site\wwwroot\wf-ReduceProposals\execute_powershell_code.ps1:9 char:24 + $domain =( @{parameters('AADDomain-(Prod)')} ) + ~ Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.'.

I hope someone knows the correct syntax for that.
Maybe I can only get environment variables with $env.{vname}?
How about PnP-Powershell? how do I incorporate it?
Thank you

are you after a hashtable? @{parameters = 'AADDomain-(Prod)'}

No I want to access the same parameters other workflows in same logic app are using. in code it looks like  "AADDomain-(Prod)": {
"type": "String",
"value": "mydomain.sharepoint.com"
},  I did find out I can use environment variables with $env.{vname}?


Access Logic App Parameters in PowerShell script code in Standard workflows

Parameters cannot be directly accessed inside the Inline PowerShell code, But they need to referenced with a variable or action output as below and I have followed Microsoft-Document and SO-Thread:
Firstly, initialized empty variable and then set it to parameters('test')

In Execute Powershell Code :
$rith = Get-ActionOutput -ActionName test
$test = $rith.outputs
$res = [string]$test.body.value
Push-WorkflowOutput -Output $res


Output:

